# When I attempt to transition between views some data is not appearing such UIImageViews: Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

Currently, I have some simple firebase login and sign up code setup by which after the user logs in or signs up their home view will display their username and a default profile image.  When I log in from the log_in controller view it works fine in showing the username and default profile image in the home_view.  However, when I transition to my sign_up view and then attempt to transition to my home view with the new user data, it shows neither the username or profile image view. I am not using storyboards.

For my sign up controller I have nothing in the viewWillAppear but I have these functions which create the user and transition the user to the home page after the create account button is pressed:

The create account button:

```
@objc func createAccountButtonClicked(_ : UIButton){
   sign_up()
}
```

The sign up function:

```
func sign_up(){
    guard usernameTxt.hasText,
    passwordTxt.hasText,
        emailTxt.hasText

        else {

            AlertController.showAlert(self, title: "Missing info", message: "Please fill out all fields")
            return

    }
    let username = usernameTxt.text!
    let password = passwordTxt.text!
    let email = emailTxt.text!

    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: {(user, error) in

        guard error == nil else{
            AlertController.showAlert(self, title: "Error", message: error!.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
        guard let user = user else { return }
        print(user.user.email ?? "Missing Email")
        print(user.user.uid)

        self.createProfile(user.user)

        if Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid != nil{
            self.goToHomePage()
        }


    })

}
```

This is a snippet from my create profile function as the rest is simply updating my firebase database:

```
func createProfile(_ user: User){

    let username = usernameTxt.text
    let changeRequest = user.createProfileChangeRequest()
    changeRequest.displayName = username
    changeRequest.commitChanges(completion: { (error) in

        guard error == nil else{

            AlertController.showAlert(self, title: "Error", message: error!.localizedDescription)
            return
        }

    })
```

And finally, this is the function that takes care of the transitioning from the sign up to the home view:

```
func goToHomePage(){
    let homeView = HomeMenu()
    homeView.modalTransitionStyle = .flipHorizontal
    homeView.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
    self.present(homeView, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

This is some code form my view did load function in my home menu which might help as well:

```
    if let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid{

        databaseRef.child("profile").child(userID).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            let dictionary = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary

            guard let username = Auth.auth().currentUser?.displayName else { return }

            if let profileImageURL = dictionary?["photo"] as? String{

                let url = URL(string: profileImageURL)

                URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: {
                    (data, response, error) in

                    if error !=  nil {
                        print(error!)
                        return
                    }
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.profileImage.image = UIImage(data: data!)
                    }
                }).resume()
            }
            self.name.text = username



        }){(error) in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return
        }

    }
```

Any help on what is going wrong with my code would help as when I run it I receive no errors even though I have my breakpoints set up. Thank you

Comment: On which screen do you want to send data?

Comment: @ZainAnjum I want to the newly created user data to be sent to the home page view.

Comment: @ZainAnjum Hi, thank you for taking your time with me, and unfortunately the after implementing your code it gives me the same outcome as before. My login page works fine still in which after logging in I get the username and image displayed for my home page, but this is not the case when transitioning from my sign up. I edited my question to include code form my home menu which is in the view did load.

Comment: try my updated answer

Comment: @ZainAnjum Thank you so much for the time you took with me.  The code works fine now.  Have a great day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now i understand the problem is with goToHomePage() function calling
Please update the following functions in your code and let me know

```
func sign_up(){
    guard usernameTxt.hasText,
        passwordTxt.hasText,
        emailTxt.hasText

        else {

            AlertController.showAlert(self, title: "Missing info", message: "Please fill out all fields")
            return

    }
    let username = usernameTxt.text!
    let password = passwordTxt.text!
    let email = emailTxt.text!

    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: {(user, error) in

        guard error == nil else{
            AlertController.showAlert(self, title: "Error", message: error!.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
        guard let user = user else { return }
        print(user.user.email ?? "Missing Email")
        print(user.user.uid)

        self.createProfile(user.user)
    })

}

func createProfile(_ user: User){

    let username = usernameTxt.text
    let changeRequest = user.createProfileChangeRequest()
    changeRequest.displayName = username
    changeRequest.commitChanges(completion: { (error) in

        guard error == nil else{

            AlertController.showAlert(self, title: "Error", message: error!.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
        self.goToHomePage()

    })
}
```